# I want to change 2 images at once

Tags: javascript

I have images in imageBox1 and imageBox2 and when I click button, is there any way that I can change images in both boxes at the same time? with JS?
For instance, I when I click "hello", I want to make image1-1 and image2-1 display together, and when I click "world", they image1-2 and image2-2 should display together.

```
    <div class = "Button">
        <button type="button">hello</button>
        <button type="button">world</button>
    </div>

    <div class = "imageBox1">
        <img src="image1-1.jpg">
        <img src="image1-2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class = "imageBox2>
        <img src="image2-1.jpg">
        <img src="image2-2.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, its possible. What is your real question?

Comment: I mean how do I write code with JS if that is possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know javascript? Share your progress and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to each button that gets the index of the button relative to the other buttons, loops through each child in each `div` and shows the `img` whose index is the same as the button's.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

buttons.forEach((e, i) => e.addEventListener('click', function() {
  divs.forEach((f) => [...f.children].forEach((g, i1) => g.style.display = i == i1 ? "block" : "none"))
}))
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Button">
  <button type="button">hello</button>
  <button type="button">world</button>
</div>

<div class="imageBox1 image">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
  <!-- image1-1.jpg -->
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=96">
  <!-- image1-2.jpg -->
</div>

<div class="imageBox2 image">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=96">
  <!-- image2-1.jpg -->
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
  <!-- image2-2.jpg -->
</div>
```

Comment: This answer looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're asking for is a way to show or hide specific images depending on which button the user clicks. If so, you can definitely do this with JavaScript.

Here's a beginner-friendly example using your HTML.

```js
// set up some variables to make the code easier to read

const helloBtn = document.getElementById("hello-button")
const worldBtn = document.getElementById("world-button")
const img1 = document.getElementById("image1")
const img2 = document.getElementById("image2")
const img3 = document.getElementById("image3")
const img4 = document.getElementById("image4")

// When the user clicks the "hello" button, run a function named handleHelloClick

helloBtn.addEventListener("click", handleHelloClick);

// When the user clicks the "world" button, run a function named handleWorldClick

worldBtn.addEventListener("click", handleWorldClick);

// this function handles the "hello" click

function handleHelloClick() {
  img1.style.display = "none";
  img2.style.display = "block";
  img3.style.display = "block";
  img4.style.display = "none";
}

// this function handles the "world" click

function handleWorldClick() {
  img1.style.display = "block";
  img2.style.display = "none";
  img3.style.display = "none";
  img4.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="hello-button" type="button">hello</button>
  <button id="world-button" type="button">world</button>
</div>

<div class="imageBox1">
  <img id="image1" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/75.jpg">
  <img id="image2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/76.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageBox2">
  <img id="image3" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/78.jpg">
  <img id="image4" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/80.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

first hide them with css
then show them when clicking by js

```js
const hello = document.getElementById("hello")
const world = document.getElementById("world")


hello.onclick= () => {
document.querySelectorAll(".first").forEach(el=> el.style.display = "block")
}

world.onclick= () => {
document.querySelectorAll(".second").forEach(el=> el.style.display = "block")
}
```

```css
.first, .second {
display : none
}
```

```html
 <div class = "Button">
        <button id="hello" type="button">hello</button>
        <button id="world" type="button">world</button>
    </div>

    <div class = "imageBox1">
        <img class="first" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=first">
        <img class="second" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=second">
    </div>

    <div class = "imageBox2">
        <img class="first" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=first">
        <img class="second" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=second">
    </div>
```